# Easy way to go some lines back in code? - in Java

Tags: java

I need some help figuring out what i should do with this problem. I have created a class with a method called "procedure" that handles the communication between the server and client (sends some commands too the server, and gets something back).

My code of this method you can see here:

http://pastebin.com/1ibGNRnr

This method "procedure" going through some steps. If i get an error in lets say step nr. 4, i should tell my program to run step 2 or 3 again. (Go back in lines if possible)

With steps, i mean everything that is between these lines:
So step 1 is the code between Verify opererator and ask operator for item number.

```
// Verify operator // <--- step 1

// Ask operator for item number <--- step 2

// Search for item name and sends it back. <--- step 3

// Ask operator to confirm name <--- stop 4

and so on:
```

So is there an easy way to do this? It should go a few steps back if error received, but NOT start from the start.

Right now , the only solution i can think of, is to make a method of each step and just run the nessary step method if i get an error.

Comment: You can use a loop :)

Comment: So if i use a while loop.. how would u then do it?

Comment: Just like Jaydee answered below :)

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap your code in:

```
boolean finished = false;

while (!finished) {
    try {
        // your repeating code here
    } finally {
        finished = true;
    }
}
```

however you would probably want to have a "catch" block that can separate out exceptions that should also cause the loop to terminate.

On a general note, you would do well to break your code down in to several methods, each of which would have one fairly small funcion. This would make your code much easier to understand and debug. A good book on structuring code is "The Pragmatic Programmer" by Andrew Hunt and David Thomas.

Comment: Apologies to whoever formatted my code. I was editing something and lost the formatting when I saved.

Comment: So you saying it would be better to split up the code in methods? and put it in another class and acess it then?

Comment: To some extent you did this in your sudo code (step 1, step2, step3, step 4). I haven't been through your code in detail, so I couldn't say which classes you need, though in general if you can make smaller logical units things start to get easier.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest 3 things

- Don't clutter your code with loops and conditions instead use switch whenever possible
- If you are dealing with exceptions then handle exception and use it
- Move each task into a function

Add a attribute to your class to manage this the state.

```
class MyClass {
    public static int CODE;
    MyClass(int i){
        CODE = i;
    }
}

public void executeMe(MyClass o){
    try {
        switch(o.CODE){
            case 1:
                //call task_1()
                break;
            case 2: 
                //call task_2()
                break;
            case 3: 
                //call task_2 and task_3()
                break;
            default:
                //default
        }
    }catch(MyException ee) {
        //change o.CODE value based on exception types and call 
        //executeMe again
        o.CODE = 1;
        executeMe(o);

    }
}
```

You could remove the breaks and let it handle if your task flow is simple.

Comment: I'm trying to do this, but can't get it to work with the code, says something like void is an invalid type for execute me..